# How to get remaining TTL for mongo Document

Tags: mongodb

I have created one collection in mongoDB for which i have created index for field "expireAt" which is a date time and set expireAfterSeconds property to 0.
As i want to set TTL at document level not at collection level.
As i know in redis i can get the remaining TTL for the particular key
Just have question is that possible in mongoDB ? where i can get the remaining time to expire for the given document.

I have searched it on google but didn't find any relevant information.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If you set the TTL `expireAfterSeconds` value to 0 for per-document expiry, the remaining time will be the difference between the current time and the TTL date field (eg. `expireAt`) in your documents. There isn't a specific server function to query this, but you can either calculate this in your app or use MongoDB's aggregation framework.

Example using the `mongo` shell to return the time left (in milliseconds) before  documents are eligible to be removed in the next TTL pass:

```
db.mycoll.aggregate(
    { $project: {
        expireAt: 1,
        ttlMillis: {
            $subtract: [ "$expireAt", new Date() ]
        }
    }}
)
```

Note: The TTL background thread runs every 60 seconds, so documents may persist for a minute or more past their nominal expiry.

Answer (score -4):

try this

```
db.hellos.createIndex( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

read more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)

Comment: I want to get the ttl left for the given document.
The command given by you just created TTL on the specific field of mongo collection.

Comment: I think this doc [here](http://hassansin.github.io/working-with-mongodb-ttl-index)  can help you more.

Comment: hi i want through the document but there was no function to get the remaining ttl of a document.
I think i will have to fetch the expired data and perform operation as per my requirement.